# XSLT split nested tables

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am using XSLT2 for XSL:FO transformation. I need to have correct page sequencing for optimizing the performance.

My XML looks like this

```
<DOCUMENT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<A>
    <B>
        <C TYPE="1.">
            <D  TYPE="1 . 1">
                <ROW>
                    <Date>06/JUN/2014</Date>
                </ROW>
                <ROW>               
                    <Date>07/JUN/2014</Date>
                </ROW>
                <Total>
                    <Amount>10.50</Amount>
                </Total>
            </D >
            <D  TYPE="1 . 2">
                <ROW>
                    <Date>05/JUN/2014</Date>
                </ROW>
                <ROW>
                    <Date>06/JUN/2014</Date>
                </ROW>
                <Total>
                    <Amount>20.70</Amount>
                </Total>
            </D >
        </C>
        <C TYPE="2">
            <D  TYPE="2 . 1">
                <ROW>
                    <Date>28/JUN/2014</Date>
                </ROW>
                <Total>
                    <Duration_Volume>1</Duration_Volume>
                    <Amount>1.00</Amount>
                </Total>
            </D >
            <D  TYPE="2 . 2">
                <ROW>
                    <Date>11/JUN/2014</Date>
                </ROW>
                <Total>
                    <Duration_Volume>1</Duration_Volume>
                    <Amount>1.00</Amount>
                </Total>
            </D >
        </C>
    </TRANSACTION>
</MOBILE>
```

My XSLT looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="DOCUMENT">  
<page-sequence>
    <xsl:for-each select="/DOCUMENT/A/B/C">
                <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="@TYPE">
                <table_row>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                </table_row>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="D">
                <table>
                <xsl:for-each select="@TYPE">
                    <table_row>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                        </table_row>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="ROW">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Date">
                            <table_row>
                            <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                            </table_row>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</page-sequence>    
</xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to have the page sequence after every 50 occurrences of ROW. Is there any way to force the page sequence after every 50 rows. Or is there a way to page sequence it so that it applies page sequence for content at each page length? As now the entire content is in one page sequence occupying a lot of memory.

Comment: What's the difference between [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283820/split-table-in-xslt) and this one? Why not apply the same method? By the way, why do separate page sequences optimize performance (or memory usage, or both)?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong the last method iterates over the ROW where as i have other values from elements above the ROW and they need to repeat in a specific way. The FO processor holds contents in memory till it reaches the end of a page sequence so by splitting to many pagesequences i can manage the memory better.

Comment: @Mathias Muller I Have solved it.

Comment: Then you should either delete this question or self-answer it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as [originally provided by Harsha](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25304979/2) (the OP) in the original question, here provided as an answer as [per the guidelines of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Credits for this answer should go to Harsha.

Note: adjusted the solution a little bit, as it used an incorrect, or illogical XPath in the `for-each-group` select expression.

Also, I removed the if-tests for `parent::*`  and `parent::*/ROW`, because they are always true, I removed the `fn:string` in value-of (the values are already converted to a string by `value-of`) and I removed the two `</table>`, because they made the XML invalid.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="DOCUMENT">   
        <xsl:for-each-group select="A/B/C/*/ROW" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv 50">
            <page-sequence>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <table>
                        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">
                            <table_row>
                                <xsl:value-of select="../../@TYPE"/>
                            </table_row>
                        </xsl:if>
                    <table>
                    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::ROW)">
                        <xsl:for-each select="../@TYPE">
                            <table_row>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </table_row>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Date">
                        <table_row>
                            <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                        </table_row>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </page-sequence>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```